# How should I set gridview pager value when row is hidden

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, pager

I have an issue where the `pager number` doesn't get updated automatically when I hide rows in the `gridview`. Do I need to set the pager value manually? Can someone suggest me on this?

**ASPX page**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="SearchResults" runat="Server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
         EnableViewState="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50" 
         OnDataBound ="SearchResults_DataBound" 
         OnRowDataBound="SearchResults_RowDataBound">
      <RowStyle CssClass="EvenRow" />
      <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="OddRow" />
      <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField meta:resourceKey="UmSellField">
            <ItemStyle CssClass="alpha" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="alpha" />
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="UmSellLabel" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"
                    Text='<%# GetUnitOfMeasure(Container.DataItem,false) %>'>
               </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**codebehind**

```
protected void SearchResults_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType.Equals(DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    {
        e.Row.Visible = showRow;
        e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = showRow;
    }
}
```

`ShowRow` is a boolean value that gets set in `GetUnitOfMeasure` function (not copied here) based on these conditions.

Comment: When do you hide rows ?

Comment: @codebrain : I hide rows in RowDataBound event as shown above using showRow which is a boolean value that is calculated to true or false in GetUnitofMeasure function that is bound to "UmSellLabel".

Comment: @Anirudh Calculation should be performed before assigning DataSource to GridView.

Comment: @Win: There are some conditions which makes the calculations to be done later. I am trying in that approach still but so far it is seeming difficult as the datasource comes from an external application.